# Do I have to install mysql on local to use a remote db(mysql)?

Tags: php, mysql, macos

To develop web pages, I am using git and working on local currently.

I installed apache2+php on my mac, os x already had got them in fact, can't access on the remote server's database though.

Do I have to install mysql on my mac to access on the remote server's db?

Or,

is it unnecessary to install mysql package?

I have installed php-mysql, not mysql.

Thanks.

Comment: Install http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/ has an option to connect the remote server's db to alter you whatever you want. See this screenshots http://www.mysql.com/common/images/products/MySQL_Workbench_Mainscreen_Mac.png

Comment: You need to install the/a Mysql *client* library. You do not need to install the MySQL database itself. Your question does not contain enough information to tell you exactly what you are missing. "Can't access" could mean anything.

Comment: @deceze Oh I thought I'd to install mysql itself on my local mac. When I execute queries to the remote server's sql database, It doesn't return anything at all. Which mysql client library that I have to install?

Comment: If you didn't have the correct library installed, you'd get a very loud error message about it. Since you don't, the library probably is not your problem.

Comment: and what I want to do is to make mysql work on php(local server)

Comment: Show code, show complete error messages or otherwise detailed problem descriptions.

Comment: @deceze the code I wrote didn't show me errors;